# Proof that Inversion changes the direction of the normal vector.

Tags: differential-geometry

The question I am working with is to show that inversion, defined by $F(q) = \frac {q}{|q|^2}, q \in \mathbb R^n$ preserves the unit $n$-sphere, but changes the direction of the normal vectors. That the sphere is fixed is somewhat obvious, since the length of any vector on the boundary is $1$, and so the denominator in the definition is also $1$, and hence $F$ fixes these points. However, I struggle to see why the direction of the normal vector changes.

I know that the normal vector of a sphere can be written as $\frac {1}{R} [x_1, x_2, ... , x_n]^T,$ where $R$ is the radius of the sphere, in this case $1$. However, when I apply $F$ to  a vector of this form, I seem to find that $|q|^2$ is still $1$. It would appear that if I want the direction to change, I will need to negate each term of $q$, but I don't see how that can happen, when length squared is always positive.

How can I show the direction of the normal vector changes? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I don't have any other tools.

Comment: Hint: you need to apply the derivative of the inversion map to the vector.

Comment: @YuriVyatkin , how do I differentiate length? I thought it was like absolute value and not differentiable when any of the coordinates are 0.

Comment: $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\|x\|) = \dfrac{x_i}{\|x\|}$

Comment: Oh I see! I made a very silly arithmetic mistake when calculating the partials. I will post a full answer to my own question, because it turns out that I asked this question because I made a very silly arithmetic mistake when differentiating.